# Angular 4 not getting landing URL from onpopstate

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the URL which the browser goes to when back button is pressed in a web page, I have added this code in my component

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {LocalDataSource} from 'ng2-smart-table';
import {TableComponent} from '../../../table/table.component';
import {PagerService} from '../../../services/pager/pager.service';
import {ActivatedRoute, Params, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import {PlatformLocation} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css', '../../../app.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  source: LocalDataSource;
  currentPage: number;
  totalCount: number;
  pager: any = {};
  paramsSubscription: Subscription;
  urlParams: Params;


  constructor(private router: Router, private location: PlatformLocation, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.location.onPopState(() => {
      console.log('Back Pressed');
      this.getURLParams();
      // Giving the URL parameters of the page from where back button is clicked 
      console.log(this.urlParams['page']);
    });
  }


getURLParams() {
    this.paramsSubscription = this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.urlParams = params;
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Methods to populate data
  }

}
```

It is detecting the back button press and displaying the parameters in console. However, the console is displaying the page from which back button is pressed and not the page it lands. I wanted to update data dynamically based on the landing page.

Is there a way to detect the landing page parameters by any methods?
Please let me know if I am missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: What is this method doing: `this.getURLParams()` I don't see it in the provided code example.

Comment: Missed that one, now updated the code!  It just gets the URL parameters, based on which I update the data part of the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.urlParams = params;
      }
    );
```

It watching for changes to the parameters of the *current* route. Try just looking at `this.router.url`.

Or subscribe to router events:

```
router.events.subscribe((url) => console.log(url));
```

Comment: Thank you much @DeborahK The router.events.subscriibe did the job.